# Set an IP in Centos for access in SSH when connected through WiFi

Tags: centos, networking, networkmanager, network-interface

I recently installed CentOS 7 on Virtual Box with a minimal installation, and I have enabled the network interface in order to show my IP and access to it through SSH when connected by an Ethernet Cable.

Problem: I can't access to it when connected to wireless network.

If I execute `ip addr show` when connected through Wireless, I get:

`inet 127.0.0.0/8`

How to set an IP for me to access through SSH when connected through WiFi?

Comment: Will the IP addresses of wired and wireless networks be on the same network ? In other words, is this a home setup with one wireless router or is it a workplace/school network, which is heavily firewalled between wireless and wired networks along with many other security measures ?

Comment: yes... the os is installed on in the company's laptop at work

Comment: Are both wired and wireless networks use DHCP or do you have static IP addresses ?

Comment: I believe both with DHCP

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that this installation was on Virtual Box. What is your host OS ? how did you forward network connections from host to the guest OS ?

Comment: Guest OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: Enabling the network interface. Modifying `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

Answer (score 0):

Add network adapter **host only** in your VM, set an ip within the range the network adapter **host only your notebook**.

That way you will be able to access your vm via ssh for any network that you are connected, you must use ip host only to connect via ssh.

A post with more details http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I add a network adapter host only? I'm not sure of what you mean...

Comment: @CrisBenois adapter hostonly is like an internal network between your notebook and a virtual machine, take a look at this post on how to add this hostonly network in your virtualbox http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1448980105-Create-host-only-network-on-VirtualBox